# What do the values on the Minecraft debug screen represent?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If you hit <kbd>F3</kbd> while playing Minecraft, an overlay appears. Some of the items, such as `fps`, `x`, `y`, and `z` are obvious, but I'm curious about some of the other values. What do they all represent?

[image: Debug screen]

Comment: If you press SIFT + F3 the graghs disappear.(FYI)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

#### Debug numbers

- **C** is the number of renderers*  being rendered over total number loaded
- **F** is number of renderers being clipped (i.e. not viewable)
- **O** is the number of renderers removed through [occlusion culling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_surface_determination)
- **E (first line)** is the number of renderers skipped
- **E (second line)** is the number of rendered entities over total entities
- **B** is the number of entities hidden
- **I** is the number of individually removed entities (the remainder of B and the numerator of E combined)
- **P** is the number of particles
- **T: All** is the total number of entities
- **MultiplayerChunkCache** is the number of chunks currently loaded into memory

- **x** and **z** are your current coordinates along the horizontal plane
- **y (feet pos)** is the current coordinate along the vertical plane of the floor you're walking on
- **y (eyes pos)** is the current coordinate along the vertical plane of your eye level (Steve's eyes being 1.620 blocks above the ground)
- **f** is the orientation of Steve: 0 is west, 1 is north, 2 is east, 3 is south
- **lc** is the height level of the highest non-air block within the current chunk
- **b** is the name of the biome you're currently in
- **bl** is the light level of the block your head is in, from block-based lights like torches
- **sl** is the level of sunlight/moonlight on the block your head is in (independent of the current time of day)
- **rl** is the maximum of **bl** and **sl**
- **ws** is your walk speed
- **fs** is your flying speed
- **g** is whether your feet are on the ground (*true* if you are, *false* otherwise)

#### Graphs

The bar graph charts frame rate over time inversely (e.g., higher spikes = lower frame rate). Green plots are when your frame rate is 60 FPS or higher.

The pie graph charts the distribution of CPU time across different parts of Minecraft:

- **[0] root (white)** is essentially a sanity check: should always be 100%
- **[? probably 1]unspecified (green)** is the time spent on things not already enumerated
- **[2] render (blue)** is the time spent on rendering the world
- **[3] tick (purple)** is the time spent on the game clock (heartbeat)
- **[4] sound (yellow)** is the time spent on the sound engine
- **[5] updatelights (salmon)** is the time spent on updating the lighting engine (usually at sunset and sunrise)

Pressing the 1-9 keys will show sub-divisions of the numbered slices of the pie chart (in addition to switching items as usual), and pressing 0 will go back up.

#### Notes

- A [chunk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunks), if you're not familiar with the term, is a section of the world, equal to 16x128x16 blocks.
- Given the context in which it appears in RenderGlobal.java, I believe "renderers" refers to a single block.
- Under the Minecraft coordinate system, X and Z are the horizontal axes and Y is the vertical axis, which [confuses players used to other coordinate systems](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12911/does-length-dilation-affect-the-y-axis-in-the-nether).

Comment: I'm curious -- what is occlusion referring to in this sense?

Comment: @Raven: [Hidden surface determination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_surface_determination).

Comment: Awesome. A +1 to your comment.

Comment: And what is that fancy graphic at the bottom?

Comment: @Denilson as far as I understand, it charts how long it to load chunks. Large, red spikes = bad; small, green spikes = good.

Comment: Red on the graph represents lost frames, or when your game runs under 60 FPS.

Comment: Guess we can use the coordinates to mark a location for later reference.

Comment: @MarkTrapp I added some information on the pie chart and corrected the lighting numbers based on my testing. Hope I didn't step on your toes; writing another answer or just telling you about it didn't seem right. The lighting descriptions are a bit awkward, feel free to edit my edit.

Answer (score -1):

There is a very good video I have of this. It explains the F3 menu / debug screen.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Whilst this video may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to quote the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.