# How do coordinates work in minecraft? (SSP)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't figure out how minecraft coordinates work and they tell specific points in a world.

Answer (score 14):

The coordinate system used in Minecraft is a little confusing, as it doesn't really correlate to what is generally used. Usually, the `X` and `Y` axes are used when talking about length and width, and the `Z` is used for height. However, in Minecraft, the `X` and `Z` axes represent length and width, and `Y` represents height.

As `X` or `Z` increase or decease, you are moving farther away from `0, 0`, or the "center" of your Minecraft world. Traveling south-east will increase your `X` and `Z` coordinates, and traveling north-west will decrease your `X` and `Z` coordinates. On the `Y` axis, 0 is the very bottom of the map, and 256 is the top of the map (or 128 in the Nether). Sea level is at 64 on the `Y` axis.

If, for example, your coordinates read `X: 300, Y: 65, Z: -200`, you would be **300 blocks east and 200 blocks north** of your `0, 0` block, and at **an altitude of 65 blocks**.

Comment: where does it tell you your coordinates though

Comment: When you hit `F3`. See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14990/minecraft-debug-screen).